# My $.getJson method is calling another action in my add cart functionality project?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

My view page code is

```
<form method="post">
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Deleteallcarts" />
        </form>

<input type="submit" class="product_btn" value="Buy Now" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Submit1").click(function () {
   $.getJSON('@Url.Action("EmptyCart", "home")',
    alert('jhfg'),
    function (data) {
        if (data = "123") {
            alert('Cart is empty');
        }
    }
    )
});
```

My Controller actions are

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Details")]
    public ActionResult BuyNow(int id)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home");

    }

 public ActionResult EmptyCart()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.RemoveAll();
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["cartList"] != null)
        {
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }


public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Whenever i click the Deleteallcarts button in debug mode it goes to Buynow action method...Plz tell me the solution for these click event redirects to emptycart action method...

Comment: you have to prevent the default action of the `click` by either returning false from the event handler or by calling `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a form with a submit button whose default action is to submit the form. Since you have an ajax request which does the form submit you need to prevent the default action

```
$("#Submit1").click(function (event) {
    //prevent the action of the click which is to submit the form
    event.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("EmptyCart", "home")', function (data) {
        if (data = "123") {
            alert('Cart is empty');
        }
    })
});
```

---

I would recommend using a submit event handler instead of click event handler like

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    //prevent the action of the click which is to submit the form
    event.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("EmptyCart", "home")', function (data) {
        if (data = "123") {
            alert('Cart is empty');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: These submit is not working....it closes the popup windows but its not working .It jsut refreshes the page and it goes to Buynoe action method